# Printer.print object vb6

Tags: vb.net, printing

I developed application which print receipts, used visualbasic powerpack libraries to print with vb6 printer class which is very handy for such task. BUT, i have anoying problem with printing dialog poping out while receipt is printing and pausing my application for time being showed.
Here is code and picture

```
Private Sub SetPrinterName(ByVal PrinterName As String, ByVal AppPath As String)
    Dim prnPrinter As Printer

    For Each prnPrinter In Printers
        If prnPrinter.DeviceName = PrinterName Then
            p = prnPrinter
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    p.DocumentName = "ERP System"
    Me.Path = AppPath
    p.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPrinter
    p.CurrentX = 0
    p.CurrentY = 10
    p.Print("Receipt")
    p.EndDoc
End Sub
```

[image: small dialog]

Comment: The code you posted does not print anything, and therefore cannot produce the dialog you provided in your image. You'll need to edit your question and actually include the code that does the printing (the part that contains `Printer.Print`). (Your code simply selects a printer by name.)

Comment: Ok i changed code, now it`s more precise.